# Ruby: Is there a better way to write the following method?

Tags: ruby

Is there a better way to write the following method (if possible converting it into a single line?).

```
def create_array(opts)
  array = []
  opts.each{|key,value| array << value}
  array 
end
```

Comment: What do you expect for `opts`?

Comment: Assuming `opts` is a hash, `opts.values` is all you need for the body of the method.

Comment: And even if `opts.values` didn't exist (which it does) you could just use `collect`, e.g., `opts.collect { |k, v| v }`. Stuff like `collect` (i.e., `map`) is something you'll want to become familiar with, but it's unnecessary in this case. Just a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `opts` is `hash` so try it:

```
def create_array(opts)
    opts.values
end
```

Comment: and you can drop the `array = `part

Comment: @w0lf yeah, but he want to take `array` from values of `hash`, not just a return them, so..

Comment: @AlexGolubenko `array` is almost certainly a local, and isn't required after the method is done executing, all you need is `opts.values`.

Comment: In saying "almost certainly", @Dave is being cautious (overly so, arguably, considering the OP's newbie status), as `array =` could refer to a method `:array=`. If one strives for perfection, it's difficult to resist the urge to include such qualifications.

Comment: @CarySwoveland IMPOSSIBLE TO RESIST